# How to enable auto refresh the Tableau(10.x) datas which is published in the website?

Tags: tableau-api

I extracted the data from `Tableau`. Then I started publishing the dashboard into my website. It worked fine but The dashboard is not auto refreshing it's value, It keeps only it's old data. To update the values again I need to extract the `Tableau` workbook. Kindly  let me know if possible to get auto refresh the values. Thanks!!!

Comment: Set up an extract refresh schedule on your Tableau Server then publish the workbook and choose the extract schedule. An extract schedule can be created by a server administrator.

Comment: Hey, Sam thanks. Server admin from our organization or tableau side?

Comment: Tableau Server Admin

Comment: Okay, Sam. Thanks! let see.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature called extract refreshes in Tableau . You need to set up a schedule and connect your datasource to it . You will be good to go